# How to check if an @NSManaged property is nil in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am adding a new property to an existing data set. I need to take corrective action (such as setting it to a default value) if the value for that property that I get from my Parse.com backend does not exist. I have gone through various solutions posted here and they do not work, I have put the Xcode error message as comments in the code below. I have tried it both in Xcode 6.4 and in Xcode 7.0 beta 5 as another post had suggested that optional NSManaged is properly handled in Xcode 7.0 Beta 2.

```
class MyObject: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
@NSManaged private(set) var newPoperty: Bool // No probs here but cannot check nil, see later on..
// @NSManaged private(set) var newProperty: Bool? // ! Property cannot be marked NSManaged as its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

private func initLaterProperties(object: MyObject) {

if (object.newProperty == nil ) {//Does not work with following messages
// Xcode 7.0 Beta 5: ! Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type Bool and nil
// Xcode 6.4: No operator found matching the operands



// Do something
}

if let test = object.newProperty { // Does not work with following message
//! Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'
}
else {
//Do something


}
}

}
```

Comment: Make it an `NSNumber?` instead of a `Bool?`.

Comment: @matt: Thanks, NSNumber? seems to go past the Xcode linter in 7.0 Beta 5. I have got too many swift 2.0 syntax changes to perform before I can say it compiles and runs. Wonder why Bool does not work. It would presumably be more storage efficient if it works.

Comment: You already know why Bool does not work. It's because Optional<Bool> is not magically bridged to Objective-C. But NSNumber is an Objective-C class, and it can store a boolean (`init(bool:)`) so you can do all the same things with it.

Comment: Thanks Matt! If you were to cut and paste your comment in an answer, I can mark it as an accepted answer! Appreciate your help. Jitendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this has to be an Objective-C-compatible property, do what you would have done if you had been writing this code in Objective-C! In Objective-C, a Bool cannot be `nil` - it is not an object. Instead, you'd use NSNumber, which has methods to hold a boolean (`init(bool:)`) and to extract a boolean (`boolValue`). So make this an `NSNumber?` and adjust the rest of your code accordingly.